# Displaying MAX Value in Scorecard on data Studio

Tags: looker-studio, looker

How would i display the highest number or peak number on a scorecard in Data Studio ?

I've tried using the MAX function but it shows the total amount of viewers instead of the max/peak during that time period. The chart that i have on the page displays the amount of unique viewers throughout a three hour period with 5 minute intervals.

Comment: The max function should show the max/peak of the data during the selected time period
https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7583208?hl=en. Are you using it in an expression or a numeric? if its an expression? and where are you setting it to max?